# OTG USB devices not detected anymore on Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 but can charge the phone and share files with computer

Tags: xiaomi, usb-on-the-go, bugs, redmi

I noticed that either USB key or the Razer Kishi gamepad where undetected by my device although it did work some time ago. It may be related to an update or a material problem, I don't know. I tried the devices on both my computer and other android devices and they are perfectly detected.

I have no setting to toggle on Settings > Additional Settings, while I saw on the internet that OTG devices have a setting to toggle on for OTG.

See attached picture for the specs of my phone.

Is there any way to confirm whether it's a software issue or a physical issue ?
And would anyone know which steps to take in either case ?

[image]

EDIT: Extra information provided:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your phone works on a charger and a PC then a general physical problem of the phone is unlikely.
The most probable problem source is an software update.

### USB-C hardware issue

But there is one exception: I assume the phone has an USB-C connector which is by definition reversible. This is implemented by providing all connectors twice.

So if one of the connectors is damaged than it may still work but only in one direction. Additionally there are devices (and USB-C cables) known that have by design problems with this reversibility, they fail to detect USB devices in both directions or have other problems in one direction.

Therefore please when connection USB devices to the phone always check both directions of the USB-C plug just to make sure.

### Software issue

There are several apps to be found in Play Store that check the OS for OTG support. Not sure if there is an app that works for your phone and Android version, but I would give it a try.

Comment: I added the results of testing the OS for OTG support to the question. I tried it by myself but did not thought it helped.

**Hardware issue:** What you mean is that I may have a device that works when it is connected to a PC ? (phone is the peripheral) but not when I connect the phone to some usb key ? (usb key is the peripheral). I don't understand what you mean by check both directions of the USB-C plug, what is an exemple of procedure you'd like me to do?

Comment: @RobinVogel All USB plugs have two directions how you can insert such a plug in a socket. Before USB-C only one direction worked, the other was mechanically blocked. Since USB-C both directions are possible, there is no "wrong direction" anymore on physical level. However some devices still have one "wrong direction" on technical level (because of a damage or a bug in the hardware design).